# How to solve a cubic function with more than hundred pairs of known dependent and independent variable in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, sympy, scipy-optimize

I try to find out how to solve a cubic function with independent variable (x) and dependent variable f(x) known but coefficient a, b, c and constant d unknown. I tried sympy but realized it only works for 4 pairs. Now I try to explore some possibilities to solve this (by finding the actual value for coefficient a/b/c and constant d). Any advice are greatly appreciated.

Below is the code which obviously does not work and returned an empty list because there are more than hundred of pairs.

```
from sympy import Eq, solve
from sympy.abc import a,b,c,d, x

formula = a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d  # general cubic formula

xs = [28.0, 29.0, 12.0, 12.0, 42.0, 35.0, 28.0, 30.0, 32.0, 46.0, 18.0, 28.0, 28.0, 64.0, 
38.0, 18.0, 49.0, 37.0, 25.0, 24.0, 42.0, 50.0, 12.0, 64.0, 23.0, 35.0, 22.0, 16.0, 44.0, 
77.0, 26.0, 44.0, 38.0, 37.0, 45.0, 42.0, 24.0, 42.0, 12.0, 46.0, 12.0, 26.0, 37.0, 15.0, 
67.0, 36.0, 43.0, 36.0, 45.0, 82.0,
44.0, 30.0, 33.0, 51.0, 50.0]

fxs = [59.5833333333333, 59.5833333333333, 10.0, 10.0, 47.0833333333333, 51.2499999999999, 
34.5833333333333, 88.75, 63.7499999999999, 34.5833333333333, 51.2499999999999, 10.0, 
63.7499999999999, 51.0, 59.5833333333333,47.0833333333333, 49.5625, 43.5624999999999, 
63.7499999999999, 10.0, 76.25, 47.0833333333333,10.0, 51.2499999999999,47.0833333333333,10.0, 
35.0, 51.2499999999999, 76.25, 100.0, 51.2499999999999, 59.5833333333333, 63.7499999999999, 
76.25, 100.0, 51.2499999999999, 10.0, 22.5, 10.0, 88.75, 10.0, 59.5833333333333, 
47.0833333333333, 34.5833333333333, 51.2499999999999, 63.7499999999999,63.7499999999999, 10.0, 
76.25, 62.1249999999999, 47.0833333333333, 10.0, 76.25, 47.0833333333333, 88.75]

sol = solve([Eq(formula.subs(x, xi), fx) for xi, fx in zip(xs, fxs)])
print(sol)  
[]
```

Comment: You've used the `regression` tag, but are using sympy to solve.... for what, the coefficients? It's not super clear what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to find the roots of the cubic equation, or the coefficients? Are you trying to fit a cubic polynomial to your data, or solve a cubic equation?

Comment: I tried to find the a b c and d from the cubic function by using the sympy but realized it did not work, so I explored some other ideas. I removed the regression tab to avoid the confusion.

Comment: I you don't actually want to solve the equation.. The equation can be solved with 4 points, and you have many more than that. You want to optimize those values to minimize your error. Use scipy.optimize insteadt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For curve-fitting, I recommend using [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go  # only used to show output; not needed in answer
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def cubic(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * x**3 + b * x**2 + c * x + d


(a, b, c, d), _ = curve_fit(cubic, xs, fxs)  # `xs` and `fxs` copied from the OP


x = np.linspace(min(xs), max(xs), 1000)


fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=xs, y=fxs, mode='markers', name='data'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=cubic(x, a, b, c, d), name='fit'))
fig.show()
```

Output:

[image: cubic fit]

Comment: Thanks ddejohn, I try to find out the actual value for the coefficient (a, b, c) and constant (d), then use these numbers to predict the target variable f(x) based on a given input variable x by plugging these numbers back into the cubic equation. For your solution above, is there a way I could leverage your work to solve the question? Thanks

Comment: Yes, just use the variables `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` from the solution above, when passing an `x` value to the `cubic()` function.

Comment: Thanks. I do see the value for a, b, c, and d, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

How you might approach this with SymPy (assuming you want a least squared error solution):

```
In [2]: errors_squared = [(fx - formula.subs(x, xi))**2 for fx, xi in zip(xs, fxs)]

In [3]: error = Add(*errors_squared)

In [4]: sympy.linsolve([error.diff(v) for v in [a, b, c, d]], [a, b, c, d])
Out[4]: {(0.00019197277106452, -0.0310483217324413, 1.68127292155383, 7.51784205803798)}
```

Comment: Thanks. May I ask what package did you import for the Add function?

Comment: It's from sympy